# How to squish in ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to squish in ruby. I have found this method in Ruby on rails but I want to use it in Ruby only because I have not use Ruby on rails.

How can do that in Ruby.

```
" foo   bar    \n   \t   boo".squish # => "foo bar boo"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the following:

```
" foo   bar    \n   \t   boo".split.join(" ")
# => "foo bar boo"
```

Answer (score 9):

From the [Rails source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/filters.rb#L15), which adds `squish!` to `String`:

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/filters.rb, line 16
def squish!
  gsub!(/\A[[:space:]]+/, '')
  gsub!(/[[:space:]]+\z/, '')
  gsub!(/[[:space:]]+/, ' ')
  self
end
```

Answer (score 8):

I see no reason to (re)implement this and not use [ActiveSupport](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport), you can use it without the whole Rails framework:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/string/filters'
" foo   bar    \n   \t   boo".squish
# => "foo bar baz"
```

Or, if you really want to avoid Rails, you could use [Ruby Facets](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets):

```
require 'facets/string/squish'
" foo   bar    \n   \t   boo".squish
# => "foo bar baz"
```

**Update** Well, maybe, perfomarmances could be a reason. A quick benchmark:

```
require 'benchmark'

require 'facets/string/squish'

def squish_falsetru(s)
  s.strip.gsub(/s+/, ' ')
end

def squish_priti(s)
  s.split.join(' ')
end

# ActiveSupport's implementation is not included to avoid 
# names clashes with facets' implementation.
# It is also embarrassing slow!

N = 500_000
S = " foo   bar    \n   \t   boo"

Benchmark.bm(10) do |x|
  x.report('falsetru') { N.times { squish_falsetru(S) } }
  x.report('priti') { N.times { squish_priti(S) } }
  x.report('facets') { N.times { S.squish } }
end

                 user     system      total        real
falsetru     1.050000   0.000000   1.050000 (  1.047549)
priti        0.870000   0.000000   0.870000 (  0.879500)
facets       2.740000   0.000000   2.740000 (  2.746178)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
>> " foo   bar    \n   \t   boo".strip.gsub(/\s+/, ' ')
=> "foo bar boo"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it yourself:

```
def squish
  string = strip
  string.gsub!(/\s+/, ' ')
  string
end
```

It's modified Rails' [`squish!`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/String/squish!) method.

Answer (score 0):

This adds a method that behaves like Rail's `squish` method to the Ruby `String` class:

```rb
class String
  def squish
    strip.gsub(/\s+/, ' ')
  end
end
```

Demonstration:

```rb
$ irb
irb(main):001:1* class String
irb(main):002:2*   def squish
irb(main):003:2*     strip.gsub(/\s+/, ' ')
irb(main):004:1*   end
irb(main):005:0> end
=> :squish
irb(main):006:0> "  Help, I   am trapped  in a  computer  ".squish
=> "Help, I am trapped in a computer"
```

Comment: Note: Rail's `squish` also converts whitespace unicode characters like non-breaking space `\u00A0`, whereas solutions that use `\s` or `split` do not.