# How to access text nodes when scraping from websites using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm scraping data from two sites.  The first scrapes fine other then duplicating the price twice.  The second site scrapes the right data, but returns a spacing issue that I'm not to sure how to fix.

```
class DailyDealz::Deal
attr_accessor :name, :price, :availability, :url

def self.today
 # Scrape woot and meh and then return deals based on that data
 self.scrape_deals
end

def self.scrape_deals
    deals = []

    deals << self.scrape_woot
    deals << self.scrape_meh
    # deals << self.scrape_steepandcheap

    deals
end

def self.scrape_woot
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.woot.com/"))

    deal = self.new
    deal.name = doc.search("h2.main-title").text.strip
    deal.price = doc.search("#todays-deal span.price").text.strip
    deal.url = doc.search("a.wantone").first.attr("href").strip
    deal.availability = true
    deal.website 

    deal
end

def self.scrape_meh
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://meh.com/"))

    deal = self.new
    deal.name = doc.search("section.features h2").text.strip
    deal.price = doc.search("#button.buy-button").text.gsub("Buy it.", "").strip
    deal.url = "https://meh.com/"
    deal.availability = true

    deal
end
```

This is returned:

```
// ♥  ./bin/daily-dealz
Todays Daily Deals
1. Apple Watch Blowout! - $129.99–$279.99$129.99$279.99 - true - 
2. 12-For-Tuesday: Fun Putty 1.8oz Tins

                                - 12 for $19 -  - true - 
Enter the number of the deal you'd like more info on or type list to see deals again or exit to exit 
program.
```

How can I remove the duplicate pricing in woot and the awkward spacing in meh?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. When asking, we need the absolute minimal code, input data, and your expected output. As per MCVE, in your question you're making us dig through the site's page to find the problem. Instead, you need to reduce your code to the smallest runnable, retrieve that HTML, strip it to the smallest possible markup that still duplicates the problem, and put it in your question too.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:

1. `#todays-deal span.price`: Three elements match this criteria. Let's make it more specific by changing to

   ```
   #todays-deal .price-holder > span.price
   ```

   to select the `price-holder` div and the first `span.price` under that.
2. The text contains new-line characters. Add `gsub(/\s+/,' ')` after `strip`.

See this [example](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/FuchsiaWorldlyInternalcommand).

Another note: `#button.buy-button` is looking for a button ID, not an element of the type "button". Change this to `button.buy-button`.

Comment: Doesn't strip remove new line characters?

Comment: @GarrettMotzner from the beginning and end of the string not from the middle.

Comment: Ah, you want to [`squish`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741474/how-to-squish-in-ruby) then, right?

Comment: @GarrettMotzner `squish` is a rails method not a ruby method and it looks like this `gsub!(/[[:space:]]+/, " ")` then `strip!` which is essentially what I posted

Comment: hey can i ask what this method was for def display 
    "#{name} - #{price} - #{availability} -#{url}"
  end   i took it out and the code ran fine ?

Comment: @superkushbuttface it was just to display the results at the end so I could show you the end result

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the Kernel's [`open`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#method-i-open), which is being overridden and which is deprecated for this use:

```
warning: calling URI.open via Kernel#open is deprecated, call URI.open directly or use URI#open
```

Instead use [`URI.open`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-open):

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open('https://www.woot.com/'))
```

Don't use [`search`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable.html#search-instance_method)...[`text`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#inner_text-instance_method) ever. `search` returns a NodeSet and if you get multiple nodes in the set, then `text` will concatenate the output, which is 99.9% of the time going to make you sorry. See the documentation for [`text`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#inner_text-instance_method) for the official statement. More about that below.

If you know you want the first, or only, node that matches, use [`at`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable.html#at-instance_method). And, often, if you're after a specific node, `strip` isn't necessary:

```
doc.search("h2.main-title").text.strip # => "Apple Watch Blowout!"
doc.at('h2.main-title').text           # => "Apple Watch Blowout!"
```

Here's where `search`...`text` is biting you. The concatenation of the text has created a string that now forces you to have to jump through a hoop to figure out what you have. In this particular case it'd be fairly easy to take apart and recombine, however if the text didn't contain "$" and "-" it'd be very difficult. This particular problem is one we see asked about too often.

The fix is simple, let `map(&:text)` iterate over the Nodes in the NodeSet and you'll receive an array of text values. And, again, you probably won't need `strip` later.

```
doc.search("#todays-deal span.price").text.strip  # => "$129.99–$279.99$129.99$279.99"
doc.search('#todays-deal span.price').map(&:text) # => ["$129.99–$279.99", "$129.99", "$279.99"]
```

Again, the same things apply. Also, Nokogiri makes it easy to access parameters' values using a Hash [`[]`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#%5B%5D-instance_method) notation. It's shorter and nice and clear:

```
doc.search("a.wantone").first.attr("href").strip # => "https://www.woot.com:443/plus/your-choice-apple-watch?ref=w_cnt_gw_dly_wobtn"
doc.at("a.wantone")['href'].strip                # => "https://www.woot.com:443/plus/your-choice-apple-watch?ref=w_cnt_gw_dly_wobtn"
```

For the second site, the problems are similar:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open('https://meh.com/'))
```

Use `tr` to quickly strip line ends from the text, then `squeeze` and `strip` will clean up the remaining whitespace:

```
doc.search('section.features h2').text.strip                         # => "12-For-Tuesday: Fun Putty 1.8oz Tins\r\n                                \r\n                                    - 12 for $19"
doc.at('section.features h2').text.tr("\r\n", '').squeeze(' ').strip # => "12-For-Tuesday: Fun Putty 1.8oz Tins - 12 for $19"
```

Using the `gsub`... "Buy" isn't in the HTML so that's wasting CPU time, and, unless you're trying to replace or strip multiple occurrences of a string use `sub` instead. It's faster.

```
doc.search('button.buy-button').text.gsub('Buy it.', '').strip     # => "Sold out\r\n                                        There are no more"
doc.at('button.buy-button').text.tr("\r\n", '').squeeze(' ').strip # => "Sold out There are no more"
```